# Form Submission in marmelab/react-admin template

Tags: reactjs

I tried to utilize [reactAdmin](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/) but i have some questions in file hierarchy why .ts , tsx and .js files are there in one use of single screen , May i know the usage of that and how to handle the API's integration within interlinking the data.

And also is there any solutions of handling .tsx functions or components in .js file as im very much familiar with .js than ts or tsx.

React AdminA Web Framework for B2B applicationsmarmelab.com

Answer (score 0):

They `typescript` files which gonna be eventually compiled to javascript. So you can just use javascript code as reference, there is no need to look at those .ts or/and .tsx file, you should look at them when you want to learn `typescript`.

It checks variable types at compile time in 'your code'.

If you are new to javascript, first learn it, and not necessary to learn `typescript`, but you "may may" need it in future.